# Regex for "everything except 34,37" WITHOUT negative lookahead

Tags: regex, vb6

Every time this is asked, the answer is to use negative lookahead like so: (?!x)

Well unfortunately I must implement an American Express check in vb6, which does NOT support negative lookaheads or negative look behinds.

Is it possible to match everything except 34, 37 using the oldest imaginable implementation of regular expressions?

I expected this sort of thing to work:
`^[1,2,4-9][1-3,5-6,8-9][0-9]{13}$`

I've been able to match AmEx with this expression of course: `^3[47][0-9]{13}$` but I haven't found a way to inverse the validation rule.

Here is my validator setup:

````
       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="AmExValidator"
            Display="None"
            ControlToValidate="txtCreditCardNumber"
            ValidationExpression="^[1,2,4-9][1-3,5-6,8-9][0-9]{13}$"
            ErrorMessage="American Express cards are not accepted."
            ValidationGroup="Payment"
            runat="server">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>```
````

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew already gave you a solution, but just to add to this -- the reason your validation isn't working is that those commas don't work the way you think you do. I.e. [1,2] isn't matching 1 and 2-- it's matching 1, the comma character, and 2.

Comment: Another way is to attempt to match what you don't want, `^3[47]`, and if that is not a match, capture what you do want: `^\d{2}`. You can do that with the regex  `^(?:3[47]|(\d{2}))\d{13}$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wpSGK5/1). That is, the string begins with something other than `34` or `37` if and only if the match is captured. If you don't need to validate the length of the string `^(?:3[47]|(\d{2}))` is sufficient. You could of course perform this task easily without a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^([0-24-9][0-9]|3[0-35689])[0-9]{13}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJ3VYG/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-24-9][0-9]|3[0-35689])` - `00` to `29` and `40` to `99`, or `3` followed with a digit other than `4` and `7`
- `[0-9]{13}` - thirteen digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well. So I was pretty close, are the commas just not acting as I expect? Are they interpreted as a literal comma character?

Comment: @BayouAerospace `[1,2-4]` matches a `1`, `,`, `2`, `3` or `4` char. Commas are meaningful.

Comment: @BayouAerospace So, did it finally work or do you need more help? I am curious if replacing `(` with `(?:` will also work for you, I guess yes. Non-capturing groups are more efficient and it is best practice to use them if we do not need the value captured.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because the regex seems correct and matches as expected in the regex101 tester, but no my validator is not functional, it's still throwing validation errors on things like 5555555555555555

Comment: @BayouAerospace `5555555555555555` has more than 15 digits. Do you mean there can be *any* number but `34` and `37` at the start of the string that is followed with 13 digits? I do not think that is the case, but at least you know why `5555555555555555` does not match.

Comment: It's supposed to be 16 digits total, right? 555555555555555 matches in the regex101 editor. I thought [0-9]{13} is 14 total digits.

Comment: @BayouAerospace `37` (2) + `[0-9]{13}` (13) = 15. Please read my explanation.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the {13}, changed to {14} and its working like a charm. Thanks again Wiktor!